# Объединить списки C1 и С2 в один упорядоченный список, изменяя только значения полей ссылочного типа

Tags: java, list

*Задание:* Во входном файле расположены два набора положительных чисел; между наборами стоит отрицательное число. Построить два списка C1 и С2, элементы которых содержат соответственно числа 1-го и 2-го набора таким образом, чтобы внутри одного списка числа были упорядочены по возрастанию. Затем объединить списки C1 и С2 в один упорядоченный список, изменяя только значения полей ссылочного типа.

---

Пока сделал до последнего предложения. Не понимаю сути вопроса, вернее просто объединить и отсортировать могу, но мне кажется это не правильно. И вообще я правильно делаю?

```
    float   c;
    List<Float> a = new ArrayList<Float>();
    List<Float> b = new ArrayList<Float>();
   
     try{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    while(sc.hasNext()){
    a.add(sc.nextFloat());
    c=sc.nextFloat();
    b.add(sc.nextFloat());
    }
    sc.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
     
     Collections.sort(a);
     Collections.sort(b);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс со списками

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ListFloat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float   c;
        List<Float> c1 = new ArrayList<Float>();
        List<Float> c2 = new ArrayList<Float>();

        try{
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
           boolean select = false;
            while(sc.hasNextFloat()){
                c = sc.nextFloat();

                if (c < 0) {
                    select = true;
                    continue;
                }
                if (!select) {
                    c1.add(c);
                }else {
                    c2.add(c);
                }
            }
            sc.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}

        Collections.sort(c1);
        System.out.println("c1:"+c1);
        System.out.println("c2:"+c2);
        c1.addAll(c2);
        Collections.sort(c1);
        System.out.println("c1:"+c1);
    }
}
```

Файл input.txt для класса выше

```
1.0
2.3
4.2
7.5
8.9
2.5
-1.73
5.1
21.2
0.9
7.1
8.0
12.5
11.8
47.5
```